# PostgreSQL PSQL client-side commands and new lines (\COPY)

Tags: postgresql, psql, client, copy

The error message is the same with super user using COPY. The files are  located on the same server as the postgres server. Saw many similar posting but not a single one answer my question.

```
\copy table_name from '/path/to/csv/file.csv'
with format csv, header true ;

ERROR: syntax error at or near "format"
```

Tied with parenthesis or not.  Read the manual at [version 10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-copy.html) for postgres carefully.  Not helping.  I must be missing some minor point, please point out.

Comment: Welcome to [dba.se] This is a really good question in that it confuses a lot of people. Please stick around. You seem to have a follow-up question which is perfectly fine. It's better to keep questions atomic though, can you ask the other question again as a separate submission here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## psql "meta-commands"

Commands in psql that start with back-slash (`\`) are called "[meta-commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)" and they don't follow the usual semicolon rules but are instead terminated by a newline. A small excerpt from [`man psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

> **Parsing for arguments stops at the end of the line**, or when another unquoted backslash is found. An unquoted backslash is taken as the beginning of a new meta-command. The special sequence `\\` (two backslashes) marks the end of arguments and continues parsing SQL commands, if any. That way SQL and psql commands can be freely mixed on a line. But in any case, **the arguments of a meta-command cannot continue beyond the end of the line.**

*Much* more said on this in the man pages. Yes, it's weird and annoying. It's because historically psql commands were a sort of metacommand you'd want to run without interrupting any query you were building, like \d to see columns of a table. But for pseudo-statements like `\copy` it gets confusing.

## What's happening here

In your case, what's happening is that `psql` runs the first line, then sends the second to the postgres server, which recognises `WITH` as a [valid CTE statement token](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) then gets confused by `FORMAT`.

What you want is,

```
\copy table_name from '/path/to/csv/file.csv' with format csv, header true
```

Comment: Sometimes I wish PostgreSQL valued sanity more than backwards compatibility. =/

Comment: Me too. Very much me too. But that said, whenever we do break BC, all hell breaks loose. `bytea_output` was a nightmare.

Comment: being that your question is dead-on, but that I predict this will be popular would you have any objection to me fixing it up a bit with more in the way of details? (you can roll back if you don't like changes)

Comment: You commented on the answer. If you meant that, then fine by me. I'm not sure it'll be that popular due to the fact that different line breaks will produce different errors.

Comment: The title is good.  I have used postgrs copy command for at least 10 thousand times in the past, but have not used it for the last few years. This one got me.  I was trying to figure out why because there was another issue with my header.  The passer just started parsing the value without consulting the with header true setting.

Comment: A *lot* of people are confused by `COPY` vs `\COPY` too. I think it's a real shame `\copy` wasn't `\CLIENTCOPY` or something

Comment: @CraigRinger I did mean that, I wanted to fix your answer up so I can dupe all the times people ask this over this question. I've seen this enough to know given enough time this will be a famous answer. ;)

Comment: Very good education for me, everything has to be in one line.